# Try to implement a page curl example in android from here

Tags: android, animation, page-curl

I have downloaded the source code from [github](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl). It works fine. I want to implement this type of application, but my problem is here in the class `PageProvider` it has:

```
private int[] mBitmapIds = { R.drawable.obama, R.drawable.road_rage,R.drawable.taipei_101, R.drawable.world }
```

If I am adding some more images in this array from my `drawable` folder, those images are not shown when I am running this code.

Tried to add more images for page curl effect. And tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: don't see no pageprovider nowhere

Comment: I think there is a method called getCount, you should return correct size of this array.

Comment: oh thanks for reply ! yes tom there is getCount method and it return 5. i m also replace it with 10 but it is not show my images. it repeated previous 5 images again

Comment: @Jeetu Could you provide the code you modified and where you are displaying the images. That might help.

Comment: mr. joseph pls download the code from [github](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace:

```
    @Override
    public int getPageCount() {
        return 5;
    }
```

with:

```
    @Override
    public int getPageCount() {
        return mBitmapIds.length;
    }
```

Then, modify the calls to "loadBitmap" method (within the "updatePage" method) replacing the last parameter (it has a fixed number) with the "index" variable. Furthermore, you can get rid of the whole switch and configure the pages like you wish (just extract the code from the switch-case you want).

**UPDATE1**

Use this method:

```
    @Override
    public void updatePage(CurlPage page, int width, int height, int index) {
        Bitmap front = loadBitmap(width, height, index);
        page.setTexture(front, CurlPage.SIDE_BOTH);
        page.setColor(Color.argb(127, 255, 255, 255), CurlPage.SIDE_BACK);
    }
```

Comment: how to change this method can you write this method here thanks jihonrado

Comment: last question how should i control index also edit again Thanks for reply jihonrado.

Comment: @Jeetu I don't fully understand your last comment. What do you mean?

Comment: @jihonrado Can the image flip in this example work with progressbar?

Comment: @pKs What do you mean exactly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827745/pagecurlmagazine-with-image-from-web?lq=1 look at this thread I want to achieve this.

Comment: hello jihonrado, i want auto update image after 10 second as page curl effect.what i do?