# TextView is not Clickable on OpenGl Curl View Effect

Tags: android, android-layout, curl, opengl-es

In my application I have requirement like this.I have number of data and I need to show that data on ListView kind of layout,now I have suppose total 6pages on each pages I want to show such data.I have listed number of textview on each page.Suppose i have 7pages so i need to make book kind of layout for that i am using this Code.https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl.

with this i am able to get such effect.As mentioned in below image.
[image]

Now my issue is,As OpenGl is converting entire layout to bitmap,i am not able to handle click event of textview.Whenever i click on textview on that time `ACTION_DOWN` method is called.and offcourse it should be called as entire layout is converting to bitmap thus we can't handle textview click event.

for making solution of this have googled and found some trick from [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859425/how-to-apply-click-listener) issue.Here mentioned to make seperate layout for handeling click listener,but not getting what exactly i have to do,as i don't have any experience in OpenGl,so if any one have idea about this issue,any one who can guide me handle click event.

Comment: Can I ask how you achieved, what you have got so far, I am doing something similar, however my pages won't need to interacted with. At the moment I was thinking to convert my layouts into a  bitmap then add it to a List (as its more dynamic than an array) and then change the pageProvider a little bit, however my curl view is now acting very weird and almost pulling out random layouts?

Answer (score 2):

The above solutions depends on your views pages. It may not work if you use ListViews on your pages or any ScrollView, you have to retest your application performance...
What i have done to get it working, is to create an extra root parent with,FrameLayout, place on top the widget, fi.harism.curl.CurlView and add PageContainer(RelativeLayout on may app).
At run time, get the drawable of your view page (View.getDrawingCache()) , and add The real PageView(witch contains click listener) to the PageContainer. Make the PageContainer alpha to 0. You have a duplicate page (transclude) to receive the page clic, the CurlView will still handle touch events for curl.