# Android page curl with images streaming from web?

Tags: android, android-layout, opengl-es

So, I am using   https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl , this project to achieve the curl functionality to create a book. But I want to achieve the same while streaming images from web directly, obviously in an asynchronous manner.

But then I would require an `OpenGL , progress bar` for the same. But I don't have any knowledge in `OPENGL`, So how can I go about tweaking this code and achieve the functionality I want.

Also , have a look at this question for more clear view of what I want to achieve...

[PageCurl(magazine) with Image from web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827745/pagecurlmagazine-with-image-from-web)

```
package fi.harism.curl;


public class CurlActivity extends Activity {

    private CurlView mCurlView;
    Button btn;
    private AQuery aq;
    Drawable d =null;
    TextView mText;
    List<String> data;
    MediaPlayer mPlayer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        int index = 0;
        if (getLastNonConfigurationInstance() != null) {
            index = (Integer) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
        }

        mCurlView = (CurlView) findViewById(R.id.curl);
        mCurlView.setPageProvider(new PageProvider());
        mCurlView.setSizeChangedObserver(new SizeChangedObserver());
        mCurlView.setCurrentIndex(index);
        mCurlView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mCurlView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mCurlView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
        return mCurlView.getCurrentIndex();
    }

    /**
     * Bitmap provider.
     */
    private class PageProvider implements CurlView.PageProvider {

        private String[] mBitmapStrings={"http://myserver.com/image/img%20p1.png",
                                          "http://myserver.com/image/img%20p2.png",
                                          "http://myserver.com/image/img%20p3.png",
                                          "http://myserver.com/image/img%20p4.png"};

        @Override
        public int getPageCount() {
            return mBitmapStrings.length;
        }


        private Bitmap loadBitmap(int width, int height, int index) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            b.eraseColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(b);

            if(index==mBitmapStrings.length)
               {
                index=0;
               }

            Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(drawable_from_url(mBitmapStrings[index]));

            int margin = 7; 
            int border = 3;
            Rect r = new Rect(margin, margin, width - margin, height - margin);

            int imageWidth = r.width() - (border * 2);
            int imageHeight = imageWidth * d.getIntrinsicHeight()
                    / d.getIntrinsicWidth();
            if (imageHeight > r.height() - (border * 2)) {
                imageHeight = r.height() - (border * 2);
                imageWidth = imageHeight * d.getIntrinsicWidth()
                        / d.getIntrinsicHeight();
            }

            r.left += ((r.width() - imageWidth) / 2) - border;
            r.right = r.left + imageWidth + border + border;
            r.top += ((r.height() - imageHeight) / 2) - border;
            r.bottom = r.top + imageHeight + border + border;

            Paint p = new Paint();
            p.setColor(0xFFC0C0C0);
            c.drawRect(r, p);
            r.left += border;
            r.right -= border;
            r.top += border;
            r.bottom -= border;

            d.setBounds(r);
            d.draw(c);

            return b;
        }

        @Override
        public void updatePage(CurlPage page, int width, int height, int index) {

                Bitmap front;
                try {
                    front = loadBitmap(width, height, index);
                    page.setTexture(front, CurlPage.SIDE_FRONT);
                    page.setColor(Color.rgb(180, 180, 180), CurlPage.SIDE_BACK);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }

    /**
     * CurlView size changed observer.
     */
    private class SizeChangedObserver implements CurlView.SizeChangedObserver {
        @Override
        public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h) {
            /*if (w > h) {
                mCurlView.setViewMode(CurlView.SHOW_TWO_PAGES);
                mCurlView.setMargins(.1f, .05f, .1f, .05f);
            } else {*/
                mCurlView.setViewMode(CurlView.SHOW_ONE_PAGE);
                //mCurlView.setMargins(.1f, .1f, .1f, .1f);
                mCurlView.setMargins(0,0,0,0);

            //}
        }
    }

    Bitmap drawable_from_url(String url) throws java.net.MalformedURLException, java.io.IOException {
        Bitmap x;

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url) .openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-agent","Mozilla/4.0");

        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

        x = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return x;
    }
}
```

----Edit----

> Also , I am using android-query library for asynchronous image/file
>   loading. Would it be feasible to use it with this project in case of
>   streaming images from web. How?

Comment: "http://myserver.com/image/img%20p1.png",
                                          "http://myserver.com/image/img%20p2.png",
                                          "http://myserver.com/image/img%20p3.png",
                                          "http://myserver.com/image/img%20p4.png" this all link not show image in browser please check your browser.

Comment: Its just for a test as I can't populate the actual URL here. You may use any image on any of server

Comment: you get my answer?@pks

Comment: @AnilMetatagg Yea it works I have commented on your answer please can you have a look at that issue?

Comment: Hey can you help me with that @AnilMetatagg

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29414/discussion-between-anilmetatagg-and-pks)

Comment: @AnilMetatagg http://stackoverflow.com/q/16397123/1503130 can you answer this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class CurlActivity extends Activity {

    private CurlView mCurlView;
   Bitmap y;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        int index = 0;
        if (getLastNonConfigurationInstance() != null) {
            index = (Integer) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
        }
        mCurlView = (CurlView) findViewById(R.id.curl);
        mCurlView.setPageProvider(new PageProvider());
        mCurlView.setSizeChangedObserver(new SizeChangedObserver());
        mCurlView.setCurrentIndex(index);
        mCurlView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF202830);


    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mCurlView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mCurlView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
        return mCurlView.getCurrentIndex();
    }

    /**
     * Bitmap provider.
     */
    private class PageProvider implements CurlView.PageProvider {

        // Bitmap resources.
        /*private int[] mBitmapIds = { R.drawable.obama, R.drawable.road_rage,
                R.drawable.taipei_101, R.drawable.world };*/
        private String[] mBitmapIds = {"your url","your url",
                "your urlg", "your url" };    //your image url

        @Override
        public int getPageCount() {
            return 5;
        }

        private Bitmap loadBitmap(int width, int height, int index) {
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            b.eraseColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
            //Uri url = Uri.parse("http://stackoverflow.com");
            //Drawable d =getResources().getDrawable(url);
            //Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(mBitmapIds[index]);
            try {
                drawableFromUrl(mBitmapIds[index]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
            Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),y);
            //Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(drawable_from_url(y));
            int margin = 7;
            int border = 3;
            Rect r = new Rect(margin, margin, width - margin, height - margin);

            int imageWidth = r.width() - (border * 2);
            int imageHeight = imageWidth * d.getIntrinsicHeight()
                    / d.getIntrinsicWidth();
            if (imageHeight > r.height() - (border * 2)) {
                imageHeight = r.height() - (border * 2);
                imageWidth = imageHeight * d.getIntrinsicWidth()
                        / d.getIntrinsicHeight();
            }

            r.left += ((r.width() - imageWidth) / 2) - border;
            r.right = r.left + imageWidth + border + border;
            r.top += ((r.height() - imageHeight) / 2) - border;
            r.bottom = r.top + imageHeight + border + border;

            Paint p = new Paint();
            p.setColor(0xFFC0C0C0);
            c.drawRect(r, p);
            r.left += border;
            r.right -= border;
            r.top += border;
            r.bottom -= border;

            d.setBounds(r);
            d.draw(c);

            return b;
        }

        @Override
        public void updatePage(CurlPage page, int width, int height, int index) {

            switch (index) {
            // First case is image on front side, solid colored back.
            case 0: {
                Bitmap front = loadBitmap(width, height, 0);
                page.setTexture(front, CurlPage.SIDE_FRONT);
                page.setColor(Color.rgb(180, 180, 180), CurlPage.SIDE_BACK);
                break;
            }
            // Second case is image on back side, solid colored front.
            case 1: {
                Bitmap back = loadBitmap(width, height, 2);
                page.setTexture(back, CurlPage.SIDE_BACK);
                page.setColor(Color.rgb(127, 140, 180), CurlPage.SIDE_FRONT);
                break;
            }
            // Third case is images on both sides.
            case 2: {
                Bitmap front = loadBitmap(width, height, 1);
                Bitmap back = loadBitmap(width, height, 3);
                page.setTexture(front, CurlPage.SIDE_FRONT);
                page.setTexture(back, CurlPage.SIDE_BACK);
                break;
            }
            // Fourth case is images on both sides - plus they are blend against
            // separate colors.
            case 3: {
                Bitmap front = loadBitmap(width, height, 2);
                Bitmap back = loadBitmap(width, height, 1);
                page.setTexture(front, CurlPage.SIDE_FRONT);
                page.setTexture(back, CurlPage.SIDE_BACK);
                page.setColor(Color.argb(127, 170, 130, 255),
                        CurlPage.SIDE_FRONT);
                page.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 190, 150), CurlPage.SIDE_BACK);
                break;
            }
            // Fifth case is same image is assigned to front and back. In this
            // scenario only one texture is used and shared for both sides.
            case 4:
                Bitmap front = loadBitmap(width, height, 0);
                page.setTexture(front, CurlPage.SIDE_BOTH);
                page.setColor(Color.argb(127, 255, 255, 255),
                        CurlPage.SIDE_BACK);
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * CurlView size changed observer.
     */
    private class SizeChangedObserver implements CurlView.SizeChangedObserver {
        @Override
        public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h) {
            if (w > h) {
                mCurlView.setViewMode(CurlView.SHOW_TWO_PAGES);
                mCurlView.setMargins(.1f, .05f, .1f, .05f);
            } else {
                mCurlView.setViewMode(CurlView.SHOW_ONE_PAGE);
                mCurlView.setMargins(.1f, .1f, .1f, .1f);
            }
        }
    }

    public  void drawableFromUrl(String url) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

        y = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for this. Yea it works better then before, but one more challenge that I am facing is how could I flip the page on button click, Actualy in my case it doesn't flip but automatically the requested page with an index gets opened without the curl.

Comment: But you cannot send network call on UI thread after Android 3.0. So how did you manage to achieve your requirement?