# Page Curl with best quality

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am working with Harism Page Curl(Open GL) https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl and its works fine.

Output is something like this:
[image]

It's not smooth too much.

I want something like this:
[image]

Comment: The documentation on the project is really nice. Besides, it is open source. Take a look at both and check how you can improve it to fit your needs. Tip: you get a smoother edges if you use more polygons to draw the page.

Comment: @Rajesh In CurlMesh.java, in constructor, there is a comment: """""""maxCurlSplits-Maximum number curl can be divided into. The bigger the value
  *            the smoother curl will be. With the cost of having more
  *            polygons for drawing.""""""""" And in all project this number is 10. What is maximum number?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `CurlMesh` class, default `maxCurlSplits` is 10. Increasing this number, increasing quality of lines of area.